# how to make text in ion-label in single line

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, ionic5

The is my code:

```
  <ion-card>
<ion-card-header><ion-card-title style="font-size: 16px;">Transfer Money</ion-card-title></ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content class="ion-no-padding">
  <ion-grid style="height: 100%;">
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center ion-no-margin ion-no-padding" style="height: 100%;">
      <ion-col *ngFor="let i of col" size="3" class="ion-activatable ion-align-items-center ripple-parent">
        <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
        <ion-item lines="none">
          <ion-label class="ion-text-center">
            <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>
            <div><ion-img src="assets/imgs/wallet/{{i}}.png" class="icon-size"></ion-img></div>
            <p class="single-line">{{i}}</p>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>  
</ion-card-content>
```

My Output is showing as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDw1c.png)

I want the text in the label in all single line without wrapping and hidden, Please anyone help me with this